# ng serve fails with Cannot find module './bom-handling'

Tags: angular, angular-cli

On a project that has been stable for weeks, suddenly getting the following error when running ng serve.

```
ng serve

Cannot find module './bom-handling'
Error: Cannot find module './bom-handling'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jbistis/Dropbox/dev/movemyyachtnow/node_modules/iconv-lite/lib/index.js:7:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jbistis/Dropbox/dev/movemyyachtnow/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:17:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32
```

Cannot figure out a way to resolve this.  Has anyone encountered this?

Comment: delete `node_modules` and rerun `npm install`

Comment: Thanks Santosh, that fixed it.